# How to write this JavaScript?

Tags: jquery

If you take a look on this post, you will see that there is a "add comment" link below it. When I click on it, a `textarea` will be added and allow user to write comment.

I am wondering how I can write a similar function?

**Updated**

Thank you everyone for your help.

I made a working code. However, if it is running with Google Chrome, I will get a terrible lag. I have to wait about 15 seconds to get the `textarea` out.

But if I run it with IE, then no problem at all... That is a very strange issue.

Here is my code for the JavaScript function

```
function testCall(id) {

var divName = "#Post-Number-" + id;

var appenedDiv = "<div class='container2' id='r1'>";
appenedDiv+="<div class='acc_container'>";
appenedDiv+=" <div class='block'>";
appenedDiv += "<form method='post' action='' id='loginForm' name='loginForm'>";
appenedDiv+="<p>My Reply:</p>";
appenedDiv+="<p>";
appenedDiv += "<textarea id='test' name='txtReply' cols='8' rows='10'></textarea>";
appenedDiv += id;
appenedDiv+="</p>";
appenedDiv+="<p>";
//appenedDiv+="<%= Html.ActionLink('Submit Reply', 'Login', 'User', new { returnUrl = Request.Url }, new { @class = 'linkButton' })%>";
appenedDiv+="</p>";
appenedDiv+="</form>";
appenedDiv+="</div>";
appenedDiv+="</div>";
appenedDiv += "</div>";

$(divName).after(appenedDiv);
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#r1').offset().top }, 100);
//$('#test').focus();
```

}

Here is how I call this function

```
<a href="#" onclick="testCall(<%:item.QAID %>);">Test</a>
```

Comment: This does not require using jQuery or any other framework/library. Although, those can be helpful.

Comment: The reason I say that is because looking into a library will just make your life easier.  You can do this in one line using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/zBUgZ/

```
<a onclick="addComment(this)">add comment</a>

function addComment(el){
    var t = document.createElement('textarea');
    document.body.appendChild(t);
    el.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/zBUgZ/1/

```
<a class="addcomment">add comment</a>

$('.addcomment').click(function(){
    $(this).after('<textarea class="comment"></textarea>').hide();
});
```

**EDIT**

Since it's more likely that the ANCHOR will have a HREF attribute, you should also `return false`:

```
<a class="addcomment" href="http://somelink.somewhere.com">add comment</a>

$('.addcomment').click(function(){
    $(this).after('<textarea class="comment"></textarea>').hide();
    return false;
});
```

And if you want to set an ID on the `TEXTAREA`, you might use one based on the ANCHOR:

```
<a id="addcomment1" class="addcomment" href="http://somelink.somewhere.com">add comment</a>

$('.addcomment').click(function(){
    $(this).after('<textarea class="comment" id="'+this.id+'-textarea"></textarea>').hide();
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zBUgZ/2/

**EDIT 2**

And, noting that you're trying to focus on the element, you can do this if you add an ID to the TEXTAREA:

Plain Javascript:

```
document.getElementById(this.id+'-textarea').focus();
```

jQuery:

```
$('#'+this.id+'-textarea').trigger('focus');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zBUgZ/4/

Comment: hi Jared Farrish, what if I have several links and have different ID? what should I do with the onclick event?

Comment: You mean the links have the ID? I would use a class to add the event handler. What do you want to do with the ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can call a jQuery function on the click of "Add Comment" link. In the function, you can do two things:

1. Show a hidden div that contains the textarea.
2. Append a textarea to the calling div to the innerHTML property.

Comment: I was trying the second method. I append the textarea to the end of my current div. It is not inside current div, but right under it. The text area shows, but I lost the focus. The page goes all the way to the top, but it supposes to set focus on the text area...

Comment: just append the textarea with an id and after appending set the focus to the id..hope that helps

Comment: Can't you try the 1st option..I generally use the 1st one...its sort of very easy to use.

Comment: the first one is easy.. but I am actually building a forum style project. If there is 100 reply, then I have to use 100 hidden div, which will be crazy...

Comment: You can use the "Edit 2" provided by Jared above..Thats the way you can set the focus.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose some validation would be in order to make this identical to the stack overflow addComment box.

http://jsfiddle.net/CKzsn/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#" title="Add comment" class='addComment'>Add Comment</a>
    <div class="hide">
        <textarea id="commentBox"></textarea>
        <button> Submit </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.addComment').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle();   

}); 

$('button').click(function() {
    $('.hide').fadeOut();
    var text = $('#commentBox').val();
    $('.addComment').fadeIn();
    $('<div class="comment">' + text + '</div>').insertBefore('.addComment');

});
```

Comment: Your's "will actually function" eh?

Comment: of course it needs some method to be saved server side. I think that is rather obvious. But yes. this will function.

Comment: "difference between mine and the accepted answer is that mine will actually function." I guess you could explain what you mean if you're going to say things like that. ;)

Comment: I guess, that could come off a bit improper. I'll remove that for you =)